# How to show multitooltip(have to show two tooltips for different line chart at same time) when hover the line in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having following code for line charts.
Here I'm showing two line charts in different `<div>` `id`s, I have added hover option for the line chart.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style>
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  .overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .focus circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 2;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<script>
var data = [{
            x: 'w1',
            y: 5
          }, {
            x: 'w2',
            y: 28
          }, {
            x: 'w3',
            y: 58
          }, {
            x: 'w4',
            y: 88
          }, {
            x: 'w5',
            y: 8
          }, {
            x: 'w6',
            y: 48
          }, {
            x: 'w7',
            y: 28
          }, {
            x: 'w8',
            y: 68
          }, {
            x: 'w9',
            y: 8
          }];
div_id ="#chart1"; 
div_id1="#chart2";        
draw_line(data,div_id);
draw_line(data,div_id1);      
function draw_line(data,div_id)
{
    width = 600,
    height = 260,
    margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    };
  width -= margin.left - margin.right;
  height -= margin.top - margin.bottom;
  // var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
  // var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom") 
    // .ticks(0).tickSize(0)
    // .tickFormat("").outerTickSize(0);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").tickSize(0).ticks(0)
    .tickFormat("");

  var svg = d3.select(div_id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "bg-color")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // function for the y grid lines
  function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(10);
  }

  // Draw the y Grid lines
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
      .tickFormat("")
    );

  // x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  //   return d.x;
  // }));
   x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })]);

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.x - b.x;
  });

  /*x.domain([parseDate(data[0].x), parseDate(data[data.length - 1].x)]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
      return d.y;
  }));*/

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Add the valueline path
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line");

  // Define the line
  var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
   

  svg.append('path')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr('d', lineGen(data));

  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }).left;

  function mousemove() {
      var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
      var leftEdges = x.range();
      var width = x.rangeBand();
      var j;
      for(j=0; xPos > (leftEdges[j] + width); j++) {}
      var x0 = x.domain()[j];
      i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
      d0 = data[i - 1],
      d1 = data[i],
      d = x0 - d0.x > d1.x - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(d.x+":"+d.y);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to add mousehover option for both the chart at same...
Example:
If I hover first line chart means I have to show tooltip for both charts at same time and same position.

Comment: why dont u add both the charts in same SVG and have a 2 tooltips being controlled by mousemove of both charts? You can even have same mousemove handler for both charts... and since the charts are similar too... you can create them from same piece of code

Comment: Here i have to use different Div.,thats why i tried to different svg

Comment: ok, that's quite possible too... you create a "g" element in both the charts... that contains ur tooltip text. Assign them specific ID's and refer to them using Jquery/javascript to update their values, visibility & opacity inside your D3 mouseover code for both the charts

Comment: sure..,i will try that